# Find out if a leaflet control has already been added to the map

Tags: leaflet

I wrote a custom Leaflet control. It's some kind of legend that may be added for each layer. The control itself has a close button to remove it from the map (like a popup). 
The control can be added by clicking a button.
My problem is that the user may add the same control to the map several times. So what I need is to test if this specific control has already been added to the map and, if so, don't add it again.

I create a control for each layer, passing some options

```
var control = L.control.customControl(mylayer);
```

and add it to my map on button click

```
control.addTo(map);
```

Now imagine the control has a close button and may be closed. Now if the user clicks the button again, I only want to add the control if it's not already on the map - something like this (hasControl is pseudocode, there is afaik no such function)

```
if(!(map.hasControl(control))) {
    control.addTo(map);
}
```

For simplicity I made an example where I create a zoom control and add it twice [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Krxldfx/y8mevuum/2/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easiest way is to check for the existence of the `_map` property on your control instance:

```
var customControl = new L.Control.Custom();

console.log(customControl._map); // undefined

map.addControl(customControl);

console.log(customControl._map); // returns map instance
```

But please keep in mind, when using the `_map` property, that the `_` prefix of the property implies that it's a private property, which you are normally not supposed to use. It could be changed or removed in future versions of Leaflet. You're not going to encounter that if you use the follow approach:

Attaching a reference of your custom control to your `L.Map` instance:

```
L.Control.Custom = L.Control.extend({
    options: {
        position: 'bottomleft'
    },
    onAdd: function (map) {
        // Add reference to map
        map.customControl = this;
        return L.DomUtil.create('div', 'my-custom-control');
    },
    onRemove: function (map) {
        // Remove reference from map
        delete map.customControl;
    }
});
```

Now you can check for the reference on your map instance like so:

```
if (map.customControl) { ... }
```

Or create a method and include it in `L.Map`:

```
L.Map.include({
    hasCustomControl: function () {
        return (this.customControl) ? true : false;
    }
});
```

That would work like this:

```
var customControl = new L.Control.Custom();

map.addControl(customControl);

map.hasCustomControl(); // returns true

map.removeControl(customControl);

map.hasCustomControl(); // returns false
```

Here's a demo of the concept on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nH8pZzkB1TzuTk1rnrF0?p=preview

Comment: Whatever floats your boat :) But please keep in mind, when using the `_map` property, that the `_` prefix of the property implies that it's a private property, which you are normally not supposed to use. It could be changed or removed in future versions of Leaflet. You're not going to encounter that problem with the second method. Added this to my answer, just to be complete :)

Comment: Well, now I had a closer look to the second version. I think it might be a problem if I have more than one customControl, wouldn't I? Something like `var customControl1 = new L.Control.Custom(someOptions); var customControl2 = new L.Control.Custom(otherOptions);` - if I now add both and remove the first one, `hasCustomControl` would return false..

Comment: You could easily write some logic to make it handle multiple instances. Don't store the instance as a direct property but in an object so you can add multiple, something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/xxpv0EDpGvbLsUTMuC4W?p=preview

Comment: If you have a firm control over the adding/removing of controls you could, at that time, set your own variable on the control object, dictating whether it's present on a map or not. It would then work similar to ._map but would be your own variable and not subject to change by the Leaflet devs. And since it would be per-control, as opposed to per-map, you wouldn't run into that "second version" problem.