# obtain the layers control from the map object

Tags: leaflet

Say I add a [Control.Layers](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#control) object on a map like this:

```
L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(someMap)
```

When I am later given the `someMap` object what is the proper way to obtain the layer control from it? E.g. I was hoping something like:

```
let controls = someMap.getControls();
```

... where I would then presumably be able to iterate and use the `typeof` operator to find the control I am interested in.

The closest I have found in answering the question is this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33147739/274677) which suggests extending the `L.Control` class and overriding `onAdd` in order to store a custom property on the `map` object. I find it hard to be believe it needs to be so convoluted as that. Plus, even if that approach was taken, how I am supposed to know that my overridden `onAdd` method does everything that the implementation in the original Layers `Control.Layers` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it is [implemented](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.6.0/src/control/Control.js#L136), adding a control to a map just leaves the control object with reference to the map object.

This means that the map object is unaware of the controls it has created (EDIT I should say: controls that were added to the map)

I guess there was no need for that. If you have a use case that shows this is a problem, you should open an [issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues).

So, I'm afraid the answer you already have is the right one.